# PHP pregmatch if between 1-6 words only

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Trying to match if string is between 1-6 words. This is matching the string even if more than 6 words:

```
foreach ($this->desc1 as $string) {
    if (preg_match("/^([\w]+[\s]*){1,6}?/", $string)){
        echo '<h2 class="first">' . $string . '</h2>' . "\n";
    }
    else{
        echo '<p>' . $string . '</p>' . "\n";
    }
}
```

The question is what is the proper syntax to match any string with between 1-6 words only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add (as Matthew Daly said) an *end of the string* anchor (`$`). You don't need to put `\s` and `\w` inside square brackets since they are already character classes. You don't need too capturing parenthesis since you perform only a check, I replace it by an atomic group (but you can use a non capturing group too `(?:...)`)

```
 if (preg_match('/^\s*(?>\w+\s*){1,6}$/', $string)) {
```

Notice: I have added optional spaces (`\s*`) at the begining of the string, but you can remove them if you don't need.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why the need for atomic grouping here.

Comment: @chuckieDub: It's not really a need, the atomic group forbid regex engine backtracks. It is no more legitimate than a non-capturing group but a little more performant. If I hear me, I will write the pattern like that: `/^\s*+(?>\w++\s*+){1,6}+$/` (terrific isn't it?)

Comment: I see, I had to read up on it again. Decent explanation here http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: @chuckieDub: You can read these pages too: http://regular-expressions.info/atomic.html and http://regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Comment: If there was a real risk of catastrophic backtracking this is ok, otherwise it just adds clutter IMO.

Answer (score 3):

You need to terminate it with $, I believe.

Example:

```
if (preg_match("/^([\w]+[\s]*){1,6}$/", $string)){
```

Comment: I would remove the `?` as well; not sure what it's doing.

Comment: @user2246674 I concur with that, and have taken it out

Comment: You don't need `[]` around `\w` or `\s`

Answer (score 0):

That should be:

```
/^\W*(\w+\W*){1,6}$/
```

The reason for `\W` instead of `\s` is that `\s` will require that the string have only word chars and spaces.